# Visual C++ 2010 - multiple unresolved externals errors after copy project to other computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, openmp, glut, glui

I wrote a C++ program using OpenMP. I was using it on my laptop without problems. Now i want to run it on my other computer (with better CPU). I copied project and all libraries (i use GLUT and GLUI), but when i try to run program i get a lot of errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Spheres_sym, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 2014-04-23 20:42:25.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\Spheres_sym.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __fltused
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
1>Pkt.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
1>Results.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
1>Sphere.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase
1>Pkt.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase
1>Results.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase
1>Sphere.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase

(...)

1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glutReshapeFunc@4 referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glutDisplayFunc@4 referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glutInitWindowSize@8 referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glutInitWindowPosition@8 referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glutInitDisplayMode@4 referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__srand referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___time64 referenced in function _time
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____glutCreateWindowWithExit@8 referenced in function _glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK@4
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__exit referenced in function _glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK@4
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all(void)" (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base12@std@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: class std::vector<class Pkt,class std::allocator<class Pkt> > & __thiscall std::vector<class Pkt,class std::allocator<class Pkt> >::operator=(class std::vector<class Pkt,class std::allocator<class Pkt> > const &)" (??4?$vector@VPkt@@V?$allocator@VPkt@@@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@ABV01@@Z)
1>Results.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all(void)" (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base12@std@@QAEXXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___invalid_parameter referenced in function "public: class Pkt & __thiscall std::vector<class Pkt,class std::allocator<class Pkt> >::operator[](unsigned int)" (??A?$vector@VPkt@@V?$allocator@VPkt@@@std@@@std@@QAEAAVPkt@@I@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "public: class Pkt & __thiscall std::vector<class Pkt,class std::allocator<class Pkt> >::operator[](unsigned int)" (??A?$vector@VPkt@@V?$allocator@VPkt@@@std@@@std@@QAEAAVPkt@@I@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (__imp_??1?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@H@Z$0
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > *,bool)" (__imp_??0?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE@PAV?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@_N@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(int)" (??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@H@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (__imp_??0?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(int)" (??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@H@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const type_info::`vftable'" (??_7type_info@@6B@)
1>Results.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const type_info::`vftable'" (??_7type_info@@6B@)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (__imp_??1?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_stringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_stringbuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@UAE@XZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Lock(void)" (?_Lock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAEXXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Unlock(void)" (?_Unlock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAEXXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::showmanyc(void)" (?showmanyc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@MAE_JXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::uflow(void)" (?uflow@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@MAEHXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::xsgetn(char *,__int64)" (?xsgetn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@MAE_JPAD_J@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const *,__int64)" (?xsputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@MAE_JPBD_J@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setbuf(char *,__int64)" (?setbuf@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@MAEPAV12@PAD_J@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sync(void)" (?sync@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@MAEHXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::imbue(class std::locale const &)" (?imbue@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@MAEXABVlocale@2@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::gptr(void)const " (__imp_?gptr@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IBEPADXZ) referenced in function "protected: virtual int __thiscall std::basic_stringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int)" (?overflow@?$basic_stringbuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@MAEHH@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setg(char *,char *,char *)" (__imp_?setg@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEXPAD00@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual int __thiscall std::basic_stringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int)" (?overflow@?$basic_stringbuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@MAEHH@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setp(char *,char *)" (__imp_?setp@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEXPAD0@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual int __thiscall std::basic_stringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int)" (?overflow@?$basic_stringbuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@MAEHH@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::eback(void)const " (__imp_?eback@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IBEPADXZ) referenced in function "protected: virtual int __thiscall std::basic_stringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int)" (?overflow@?$basic_stringbuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@MAEHH@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Pninc(void)" (__imp_?_Pninc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEPADXZ) referenced in function "protected: virtual int __thiscall std::basic_stringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int)" (?overflow@?$basic_stringbuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@MAEHH@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setp(char *,char *,char *)" (__imp_?setp@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEXPAD00@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual int __thiscall std::basic_stringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int)" (?overflow@?$basic_stringbuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@MAEHH@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::pbase(void)const " (__imp_?pbase@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IBEPADXZ) referenced in function "protected: virtual int __thiscall std::basic_stringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int)" (?overflow@?$basic_stringbuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@MAEHH@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::epptr(void)const " (__imp_?epptr@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IBEPADXZ) referenced in function "protected: virtual int __thiscall std::basic_stringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int)" (?overflow@?$basic_stringbuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@MAEHH@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::pptr(void)const " (__imp_?pptr@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IBEPADXZ) referenced in function "protected: virtual int __thiscall std::basic_stringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int)" (?overflow@?$basic_stringbuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@MAEHH@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _memcpy referenced in function "public: static char * __cdecl std::char_traits<char>::copy(char *,char const *,unsigned int)" (?copy@?$char_traits@D@std@@SAPADPADPBDI@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::gbump(int)" (__imp_?gbump@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEXH@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual int __thiscall std::basic_stringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::pbackfail(int)" (?pbackfail@?$basic_stringbuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@MAEHH@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::egptr(void)const " (__imp_?egptr@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IBEPADXZ) referenced in function "protected: virtual int __thiscall std::basic_stringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::underflow(void)" (?underflow@?$basic_stringbuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@MAEHXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::pbump(int)" (__imp_?pbump@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEXH@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual class std::fpos<int> __thiscall std::basic_stringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::seekoff(__int64,int,int)" (?seekoff@?$basic_stringbuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@MAE?AV?$fpos@H@2@_JHH@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) __int64 const std::_BADOFF" (__imp_?_BADOFF@std@@3_JB)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__memmove referenced in function "public: static char * __cdecl std::char_traits<char>::move(char *,char const *,unsigned int)" (?move@?$char_traits@D@std@@SAPADPADPBDI@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::~_Container_base12(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::_String_val<char,class std::allocator<char> >::~_String_val<char,class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (??1?$_String_val@DV?$allocator@D@std@@@std@@QAE@XZ)
1>Results.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::~_Container_base12(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct std::_Iterator_base12 * * __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Getpfirst(void)const " (__imp_?_Getpfirst@_Container_base12@std@@QBEPAPAU_Iterator_base12@2@XZ) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall std::vector<class Pkt,class std::allocator<class Pkt> >::_Orphan_range(class Pkt *,class Pkt *)const " (?_Orphan_range@?$vector@VPkt@@V?$allocator@VPkt@@@std@@@std@@IBEXPAVPkt@@0@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Container_base12(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::_Vector_val<class Pkt,class std::allocator<class Pkt> >::_Vector_val<class Pkt,class std::allocator<class Pkt> >(class std::allocator<class Pkt>)" (??0?$_Vector_val@VPkt@@V?$allocator@VPkt@@@std@@@std@@QAE@V?$allocator@VPkt@@@1@@Z)
1>Results.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Container_base12(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (__imp_??0?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::basic_stringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_stringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(int)" (??0?$basic_stringbuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@H@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __CxxThrowException@8 referenced in function __catch$?reserve@?$vector@VPkt@@V?$allocator@VPkt@@@std@@@std@@QAEXI@Z$0
1>Results.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxThrowException@8
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall std::vector<class Pkt,class std::allocator<class Pkt> >::_Xlen(void)const " (?_Xlen@?$vector@VPkt@@V?$allocator@VPkt@@@std@@@std@@IBEXXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::_Xran(void)const " (?_Xran@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEXXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setstate(int,bool)" (__imp_?setstate@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXH_N@Z) referenced in function __catch$??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z$0
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __int64 __thiscall std::ios_base::width(__int64)" (__imp_?width@ios_base@std@@QAE_J_J@Z) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *)" (??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const *,__int64)" (__imp_?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE_JPBD_J@Z) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *)" (??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputc(char)" (__imp_?sputc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEHD@Z) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *)" (??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::rdbuf(void)const " (__imp_?rdbuf@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEPAV?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@XZ) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *)" (??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: char __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::fill(void)const " (__imp_?fill@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEDXZ) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *)" (??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall std::ios_base::flags(void)const " (__imp_?flags@ios_base@std@@QBEHXZ) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *)" (??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __int64 __thiscall std::ios_base::width(void)const " (__imp_?width@ios_base@std@@QBE_JXZ) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *)" (??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _strlen referenced in function "public: static unsigned int __cdecl std::char_traits<char>::length(char const *)" (?length@?$char_traits@D@std@@SAIPBD@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::flush(void)" (__imp_?flush@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV12@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (??0sentry@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE@AAV12@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::tie(void)const " (__imp_?tie@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEPAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (??0sentry@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE@AAV12@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall std::ios_base::good(void)const " (__imp_?good@ios_base@std@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (??0sentry@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE@AAV12@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Osfx(void)" (__imp_?_Osfx@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry(void)" (??1sentry@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE@XZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl std::uncaught_exception(void)" (__imp_?uncaught_exception@std@@YA_NXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry(void)" (??1sentry@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE@XZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(class std::exception const &)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>Results.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(class std::exception const &)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(char const * const &)" (__imp_??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBD@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::bad_alloc::bad_alloc(char const *)" (??0bad_alloc@std@@QAE@PBD@Z)
1>Results.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(char const * const &)" (__imp_??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBD@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual char const * __thiscall std::exception::what(void)const " (?what@exception@std@@UBEPBDXZ)
1>Results.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual char const * __thiscall std::exception::what(void)const " (?what@exception@std@@UBEPBDXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall std::exception::~exception(void)" (__imp_??1exception@std@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall std::bad_alloc::~bad_alloc(void)" (??1bad_alloc@std@@UAE@XZ)
1>Results.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall std::exception::~exception(void)" (__imp_??1exception@std@@UAE@XZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(class std::exception const &)" (__imp_??0exception@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::bad_alloc::bad_alloc(class std::bad_alloc const &)" (??0bad_alloc@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>Results.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(class std::exception const &)" (__imp_??0exception@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Swap_all(struct std::_Container_base12 &)" (__imp_?_Swap_all@_Container_base12@std@@QAEXAAU12@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall std::vector<class Sphere,class std::allocator<class Sphere> >::_Assign_rv(class std::vector<class Sphere,class std::allocator<class Sphere> > &&)" (?_Assign_rv@?$vector@VSphere@@V?$allocator@VSphere@@@std@@@std@@QAEX$$QAV12@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _atexit referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'code''(void)" (??__Ecode@@YAXXZ)
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\Tomek\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Spheres_sym\Debug\Spheres_sym.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 123 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:03.67
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I use Visual Studio 2010 and Windows 7 on both computers. How can i solve that?

Comment: Try doing a clean build

Comment: @Matt McNabb - I created new project and now everything looks fine. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Are the libraries under the exact same path names that they used to be? If they are .dll s does the system PATH variable include the new libs on the new machine?

Comment: I use GLUT and GLUI libraries (http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~mjb/cs553/gettingglut.html). Path variable doesn't need to include these libs.